# Determining moving ratios over a list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

To know how fast values in a list approach 1 I tried

```
#[[1]]/#[[2]] & /@ Partition[{5040, 1460, 280, 76, 16, 2, 1}, 2, 1]
```

This works, but I seek a better method, perhaps through mapping a function over the list:

```
f /@ {5040, 1460, 280, 76, 16, 2, 1}
```

What could be the form of this `f`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
list = {5040, 1460, 280, 76, 16, 2, 1};
```

#### [`Ratios`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ratios.html):

```
1 / Ratios @ list
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

```
Reverse @ Ratios @ Reverse @ list
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

#### [`Divide`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divide.html):

```
Divide[Most @ #, Rest @ #]& @ list
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

#### [`MovingMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html):

```
MovingMap[Divide @@ # &, list, 1]
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

#### [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
BlockMap[Divide @@ # &, list, 2, 1]
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

#### `Partition` + `Divide`:

```
Divide @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

```
Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Divide]
```

> {252/73, 73/14, 70/19, 19/4, 8, 2}

Comment: +1 There is also `Most[#]/Rest[#]&@list`. Of these, `Reverse@Ratios@Reverse@list` is the quickest (`RepeatedTiming`) for this size list.